# My counter is not properly being divided by str.length(). C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I just need some help dividing my counter of the Gs and Cs in the string/DNA strand and divide those by the length of the DNA strand to get a double representing the percentage of Cs and Gs in the string. However, when I divide counter by DNA.length() it returns 0. it doesn't give me the actual answer/ by product. Please help!!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include<string>
    using std::string; using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

    double get_gc_content(const string& dna)
    {
      int counter = 0;

        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < dna.size();++i)
        {
            if(char(dna[i]=='C') || char(dna[i]=='G'))
            {
                counter++;
                // cout<<counter<<endl;     
            }

        }
      cout<<counter<<endl;

      double gc_content = counter / dna.length();

      return gc_content;
    }


    int main()
    {
      std::string dna = "ACCGCAAATT";

      double gc_count;

      gc_count = get_gc_content(dna);
      
      cout<<gc_count<<endl;

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `double gc_content = counter / dna.length();` -- An integer divided by an integer will give you an integer.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get rid of those `char` casts in the `if` statement. `if (dna[i] == 'C' || dna[i] == 'G')` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
double gc_content = counter / dna.length();
```

performs integer division since both numerator and denominator are integer types.  Thus the result will be truncated to an integer and stored in `gc_content`.

It doesn't matter if `gc_content` is a `double` -- the result of the division already occurred before the value is stored in `gc_content`.  In your case, probably `dna.lengh()` is less than `counter`, thus you are getting a value of `0.0`.

The solution is to ensure that either `counter` or `dna.length()` is casted to a `double`, so that floating point division actually occurs.

```
double gc_content = static_cast<double>(counter) / dna.length();  // For example.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the following expression:

```
double gc_content = counter / dna.length();
```

You are dividing the integer value `counter` by another integer `dna.length()` and the result of this operation will be an integer value too. Since `counter < dna.length()` in your example, the result of this operation is `0`. Following, this result is converted to a `double` and assigned to `gc_content`.

What you need to correctly compute the `gc_content` is to cast the integer values to `double` prior to the operation. That is, you could write:

```
double gc_content = double(counter) / double(dna.length());
```

Now, the result of the operation will be a `double` value which will then be assigned to `gc_content`.

There is another flaw in your code in the `if` condition. When you evaluate `

```
char(dna[i]=='G')
```

you are computing a `bool` value, which results from the expression `dna[i]=='G'`, then casting this value to a `char`. Following, this value is cast to `bool` again to evaluate the condition of the `if` statement.

You should simply use:

```
if(dna[i] == 'C' || dna[i] == 'G')
```

because the overloaded `operator[]` in the `std::string` class already returns a `char` type.